# Can anyone solve this integral analytically or by induction?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

Solve the integral

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=  \int_{X_{0\ell}} \int_{Y_{0\ell}}  \left[\sum_{\ell=1}^{m_{1}}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right]^{k_{1}}  \left[\sum_{\ell=1}^{m_{2}}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right]^{k_{2}} \\
& \times exp\left[-h_{1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{m_{1}}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right]exp\left[-h_{2}\sum_{\ell=1}^{m_{1}}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right] d{X_{0\ell}} d{Y_{0\ell}} 
\end{aligned}
$$
The integration is over $-\infty<{X_{0\ell}},{Y_{0\ell}}<\infty$, where ($k_{1}$ , $k_{2}$) are real positive integers and ($h_{1}$,$h_{2}$) are real positive numbers.
A special case of the integral is when $m_{1}=m_{2}=m$, then the integral is reduced to
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=  \int_{X_{0\ell}} \int_{Y_{0\ell}}  \left[\sum_{\ell=1}^{m}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right]^{k_{1}+k_{2}} exp\left[-(h_{1}+h_{2})\sum_{\ell=1}^{m}\left(x_{0 \ell}^{2}+y_{0 \ell}^{2}\right)\right] d{X_{0\ell}} d{Y_{0\ell}} 
\end{aligned}
$$
The above integral can be evaluated easily by doing a change the variable. We use the hyper-spherical coordinates
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{01} &= t\operatorname{cos}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \\
y_{01} &=t\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \cos \left(\theta_{2}\right) \\
x_{02} &=t\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \sin \left(\theta_{2}\right) \cos \left(\theta_{3}\right) \\
& \vdots \\
x_{0 m_{k}} &=t\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \sin \left(\theta_{2}\right) \cdots \cos \left(\theta_{2 m_{k}-1}\right) \\
y_{0 m_{k}} &=t\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \sin \left(\theta_{2}\right) \cdots \sin \left(\theta_{2 m_{k}-1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
The Jacobian will be
$$
|J|=t^{2 m-1} \sin ^{2 m-2}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \sin ^{2 m-3}\left(\theta_{2}\right) \cdots \sin \left(\theta_{2 m-2}\right)
$$
Then the integral is changed to
$$
\begin{aligned}
 I=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} \int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\pi} \int_{\theta_{2}=0}^{\pi} \cdots \int_{\theta_{2m-1}=0}^{2\pi}& t^{2 m-1} \sin ^{2 m-2}\left(\theta_{1}\right) \sin ^{2 m-3}\left(\theta_{2}\right) \cdots \sin \left(\theta_{2 m-2}\right)\\
 & \times  t^{2(k_{1}+k_{2})} \:\:e^{-(h_{1}+h_{2})t^2} \:\: d \theta_{1} d \theta_{2} \cdots d \theta_{2 m-1} \:\: d t
 \end{aligned}
$$
The integral over angles can be evaluated by  mathematical induction, and by letting $t^2=u$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
 I=\frac{\pi^m}{\Gamma(m)}\int_{u=0}^{\infty}
 u^{(k_{1}+k_{2}+m-1)} \:\:e^{-(h_{1}+h_{2})u}  \:\: d u
 \end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
 =\frac{\pi^m}{\Gamma(m)}
 \Gamma(k_{1}+k_{2}+m) \:\:(h_{1}+h_{2})^{-(k_{1}+k_{2}+m)}
 \end{aligned}
$$
Now, can we solve it for $m_{1} \neq m_{2}$, supposing that $m_{2}>m_{1}$?

Comment: There's a small typo in the very first formula, I think.  Shouldn't the second occurrence of $h_1$ be $h_2$?

Comment: No, $h_1 \neq h_2$ in both cases.

Comment: $h_2$ occurs nowhere in the first formula.  I mean that you typed $h_1$ when you meant to type $h_2$

Comment: Yes, by mistake. I will edit it right away. Thanks for the note.

Comment: saulspatz, can you please share the problem, It will be so nice of you.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it.  I just noticed the typo.